# Run / Stop / Change app working on elastic beanstalk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an app deployed through pipeline to elastic beanstalk - ec2 and I know it resides inside `/var/app/current`. And now I have to run some script there so I need to stop it, change it and finally run again. Can I do that using terminal? (connected via ssh with success)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say how to do it over ssh. If you do accomplish it in this way you will have to manually run this script each time this app is deployed. Beanstalk will start up the application with a clean state every time it is redeployed.

I believe its best to make running this script as part of the pipeline that deploys to beanstalk. The hooks section of the AppSpec can be used to setup your EC2 environment before your app starts up.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-server